# Google +1 (plusone) custom button

Tags: google-plus-one

This has been covered a great deal and seems to have mixed answers. I would like to implement my own text (not image) for the +1 button.

This is what I am trying to implement, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: I think you *must* keep the same button as Google's. They wish to make things consistent so the users "knows where to click" if you get me.

Comment: Totally understandable but it's just so ugly and clashes with my design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible, maybe, but not covered by the [Google +1 button policy](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html):

> Publishers may not alter or obfuscate the +1 Button ...

Comment: Apparently it's possible to retrieve the number of +1's via this method: http://www.johndyer.name/post/Getting-Counts-Twitter-Links-Facebook-Likes-Shares-and-Google-Plus-One-Buttons.aspx

I understand the policy however, I am doing nothing malicious to the button. It is merely a design flaw to use the default.

Comment: I'd think Google made this policy because they do want to look their +1 button the same everywhere, for various reasons. Google probably fears that as soon as they'll allow custom buttons, it'll be difficult to draw the line between *malicious* and *design*.

Comment: What a disappointment. Thanks marapet!